# deviceToken of IOS Device

Tags: xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am using Monotouch for mac and have gone through the steps to retrieve a provisioning profile certificate enabling push notification in the process. I have a working app and am now experimenting with apns-sharp and moon-apns but cant' figure out how to **retrieve my device token**. I'm hoping someone can provide me with **detailed and straightforward steps** to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `FinishedLaunching` method, register the app for remote notifications, through the `UIApplication` object you get in it:

```
// Pass the UIRemoteNotificationType combinations you want
app.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert |
 UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound);
```

Then, in your `AppDelegate` class, override the `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` method:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    // The device token
    byte[] token = deviceToken.ToArray();
}
```

You also have to override the `FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications` method, to handle the error, if any:

```
public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSError error)
{
    // Do something with the error
}
```

Comment: do I have to go through all these steps?...Isnt there a way to retrieve the actual hex value of the device id?

Comment: No, there isn't another way. Your app has to register for remote notifications every time it starts. If you are referring to the UDID, retrieving it on iOS 5+ will get your app rejected. Furthermore, the device token for remote notifications is different than the UDID and is based on your provisioning profile, notification types etc.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS deviceToken has changed.  The following code worked for me to convert deviceToken as NSData to a string.

```
string deviceTokenString;
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
{
    deviceTokenString = BitConverter.ToString(deviceToken.ToArray()).Replace("-", string.Empty);
}
else
{
    deviceTokenString = Regex.Replace(deviceToken.ToString(), "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me this was only half of the resolution. To use the DeviceToken from a webserver (PHP in my case), the DeviceToken needs to be a Hex String used in the PHP code for firing the Push Notification (e.g. as shown here: [[Using PHP to send iOS Push Notifications via APNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130938/using-php-to-send-ios-push-notifications-via-apns)][1])

However, the NSdata object offers no simple way to provide that Hex String.

So my "RegisteredForRemoteNotifications" success handler is now:

```
        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        // Get current device token
        var DeviceToken = Tools.ByteToHex(deviceToken.ToArray());
        string DeviceID = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.IdentifierForVendor.AsString();
        System.Console.WriteLine("### UserNotification Device Token = " + DeviceToken + ", DeviceID = " + DeviceID);

        // Get previous device token
        var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

        // Has the token changed?
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
        {
            //### todo: Populate POSTdata set
            //### todo: Send POSTdata to URL 

            // Save new device token
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");
            }
        }
```

And for the Byte to Hex Conversion:

```
public static string ByteToHex(byte[] data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in data)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Now you can use the DeviceToken in PHP to create the PushNotification submission.