# Where do i install APNS certification on my server?

Tags: ios

I have the certificate from the Apple Push Notification Services. My App developer has not idea on how to install that on the server and neither do I. My server information

```
Apache Version  2.2.34
PHP Version         5.6.30
MySQL Version   5.6.41-84.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in the same path as your php script that contains the code to trigger the push for example in terms of local Mamp

```
hdocs
 scrip.php ----------=> access would be $pushCertAndKeyPemFile = 'certificate.pem';
 certificate.pem
```

For php code example look here [Using PHP to send iOS Push Notifications via APNs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130938/using-php-to-send-ios-push-notifications-via-apns)