# Detached Expo (ExpoKit) Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, expo

I've just detached my expo project to ExpoKit and I'm trying to figure out how to handle push notifications. On Android, I have FCM, which worked out of the box right after I did the expo eject, the AndroidManifest.xml was correctly populated and the FCM_ENABLED in AppContastants.java was set to TRUE.

On the other hand, on iOS, I find it a bit more complicated, I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track because there are so many different approaches all over the internet. From what I understood, one can still use the Notifications from React, but he needs to provide the certificates. Can someone confirm this? Because I've generated my own certificates, enabled everything related in XCode and it still does not work.

I've also tried adding PushNotificationsIOS, added all the methods in the AppDelegate.m, the code builds, but I don't get any push notifications on iOS. I'm not even sure if I need to write some code in the react-native app, not only in the native code.

Right now, in my react native code I'm using Notifications imported from Expo and I'm using the method Notification.getExpoPushTokenAsync(), but I saw that I should use getDevicePushTokenAsync instead of this, which will return a token, either FCM or APNS. In order to call this method I need to pass it a config, which would be the sender id, but that means that I need to have a firebase project for iOS also?

TL;DR Can you still use Notifications from Expo with ExpoKit? If yes, how do you do it?

If you cannot use them, what are the options for iOS and also Android? I saw OneSignal, but it has some legal limitations and FCM does not work with iOS.

Any input will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Servus, Pati :)

Comment: Could you share your code?
How is device registered for notifications and are necessary permissions granted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130938/using-php-to-send-ios-push-notifications-via-apns/55037242#55037242 Try this

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Expo so I can't answer your first question, but I did have a very good experience with [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) for both iOS and Android. Here is a great [guide on how to get started with notifications](https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591). Along with notifications React Native Firebase offers many other compelling features such as crash reports, logging, etc.